# Is there a way to subscribe to tf data?

Tags: ros, subscribe, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Up to now, I have used tf as described in the tutorial [*Writing a tf listener*](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29): Whenever I need some positions transformed, I just use *lookupTransform*.

I am considering using tf data to control a robot and would like the robot to react whenever new tf information becomes available, i.e. *subscribe* to tf data. Is this possible at all?

The only possible way I see at the moment is having a polling loop as [shown](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29#The_Code) in the tutorial. This is bad because it introduces latency (especially if I choose a low rate) and wastes cpu time (especially if I choose a high rate).

Is there really no different option?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11706/is-there-a-way-to-subscribe-to-tf-data?/) by [sebsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/23/sebsch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 790 on 2011-10-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2011-10-27**:
I'm interested in this as well. So far I used a workaround - publishing a on dummy topic every time I publish a new tf. Then I subscribe to the dummy topic and use it as a trigger to lookup the tf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a topic "/tf" where tf information is published on as type tf/tfMessage (which contains the actual transforms). Why not subscribe to that? All tf information will be published on that topic however, so you may have to inspect the messages and only trigger your control on the right transforms.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joan](https://answers.ros.org/users/881/joan/) on 2011-11-27**:
Maybe you should also check the tf::MessageFilter http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Using%20Stamped%20datatypes%20with%20tf%3A%3AMessageFilter

**Comment by [sebsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/23/sebsch/) on 2011-10-27**:
Seems like I could not see the wood for the trees. Of course, this is exactly what I need. Thanks!